# Utilizing nested loops Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am Python noob trying to learn a coding exercise I found online.  I have a number of chicken nuggets that I need to purchase and the nuggets come in three different pack sizes (6,9, and 20).

I need to setup up a function that optimizes my purchase (maximizing the 20packs first, then the 9 pack, then the 6 pack).  The first priority is making sure there is no remainder and THEN optimizing for pack size.  so for 139 the answer would be 5 20-packs, 3 9-packs, and 2 6-packs.  Currently I've done the function using a series of nested while loops but I know there has to be a much more elegant solution.

Thanks for your help!

```
def nuggets(nuggs_needed):
    packs = [6,9,20]
    twenty_counter = nuggs_needed//20 # Start 20 pack counter with largerst divisable number#
    ttl_nuggs=0
    while twenty_counter>=0:
        ttl_nuggs = 0
        twenty_nuggs_ttl = twenty_counter*20 #total nuggest for 20 pack#
        new_nuggs_needed = nuggs_needed-twenty_nuggs_ttl #remaining nuggs after 20 pack#

        nine_counter = new_nuggs_needed//9
        while nine_counter>=0:
            nine_nuggs_ttl = nine_counter*9
            ttl_nuggs = twenty_nuggs_ttl+nine_nuggs_ttl                
            new_nuggs_needed = nuggs_needed-ttl_nuggs

            six_counter = new_nuggs_needed//6
            while six_counter>=0:
                six_nuggs_ttl = six_counter*6
                ttl_nuggs = twenty_nuggs_ttl+six_nuggs_ttl+nine_nuggs_ttl
                new_nuggs_needed = nuggs_needed-ttl_nuggs
                print '{0} 20packs, {1} 9packs, {2} 6packs = {3}total nuggets'.format(twenty_counter,nine_counter,six_counter,ttl_nuggs)
                if ttl_nuggs == nuggs_needed:
                    print 'Thats it: {0} 20packs, {1} 9packs, {2} 6packs = {3}total nuggets'.format(twenty_counter,nine_counter,six_counter,ttl_nuggs)
                    print 'Hooray!'
                    break
                six_counter-=1

            if ttl_nuggs == nuggs_needed:
                break
            nine_counter-=1

        if ttl_nuggs == nuggs_needed:
                break  
        twenty_counter-=1



nuggets(139)
```

Comment: in regards to elegance this could be a great opportunity to learn about recursion!

Comment: I am learning recursion nowadays and explore every opportunity where I can apply it. Please Check my answer for iterative and recursive solution and compare.

Comment: What is it that you want to do in the case of 27? Do you really want to do 1 20-pack, 1 6-pack, and 1 leftover, or would you rather do 3 9-packs?

Comment: @BrandonHumpert The preference is to "fill" the order completely so 3 9packs would be preferred over 1 20-pack and a 6-pack.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract from the total nuggets needed in a single loop:

```
packs = [20,9,6]
s = nuggs_needed
res = []
for num in sorted(packs, reverse=True):
    print s
    r = s//num
    res.append(r)
    s = s - r*num
```

The numbers in `res` will be the number of each type of pack you need. When the loop is done, `s` will be the number of nuggets you couldn't buy. Hope it helps!

Comment: if you use `for num in sorted(packs, reverse=True):` then you don't need to be careful to ensure that `packs` lists the numbers in descending order :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
def nuggs(num_needed, sizes=(6, 9, 20)):
    result = {}
    remaining = num_needed

    for size in sorted(sizes, reverse=True):
        result[size] = remaining // size
        remaining = remaining % size

    if remaining > 0:
        result[min(sizes)] += 1  # add one of the smallest pack-size if there are any left :)

    print '{} Nuggets:'.format(num_needed)
    print ', '.join(['{} x {}-packs'.format(result[size], size)
                    for size in sorted(sizes, reverse=True)])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at [divmod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) for this kind of problem. Something like this:

```
def nuggets(needed):
    twenties, remaining = divmod(needed, 20)
    nines, remaining = divmod(remaining, 9)
    sixes, remaining = divmod(remaining, 6)
    print "{0} 20packs, {1} 9packs, {2} 6packs ({3} unaccounted for) = {4} total nuggets".format(twenties, nines, sixes, remaining, needed)
```

Note that you haven't accounted for left-over nuggets (unobtainable quantities).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in haste and do not want to think anything else, this will do:

```
arrangement=[int(nugg/20),int((nugg%20)/9),int(int((nugg%20)/9)/6), \
             int(int((nugg%20)%9)%6)]
[6,2,0,1]

6- of 20 containing packs
2- of 9 containing packs
0- of 6 containing packs
1- of remaining items
```

**Simple if/else ITERATIVE SOLUTION:**

```
def optimize_nugg(nugg_needed):
    remaining=nugg_needed
    list_20_9_6=[]
    while(remaining>0):

        if(nugg_needed>=20):
            list_20_9_6.append(int(nugg_needed/20))
            remaining=nugg_needed%20

        if(nugg_needed>=9 and nugg_needed<20):
            list_20_9_6.append(int(nugg_needed/9))
            remaining=nugg_needed%9

        if(nugg_needed>=6 and nugg_needed<9):
            list_20_9_6.append(int(nugg_needed/6))
            remaining=nugg_needed%6

        if(nugg_needed<6):
            list_20_9_6.append(remaining)
            remaining=0

        nugg_needed=remaining



    print(list_20_9_6)
```

**RECURSIVE SOLUTION:**

```
def optimize_nugg(nugg_needed):
    print("the nugg needed here is ",nugg_needed)
    if(nugg_needed==0):
        return
    else:
        if(nugg_needed>=20):
            return int(nugg_needed/20), optimize_nugg(nugg_needed%20)
        if(nugg_needed>=9):
            return int(nugg_needed/9), optimize_nugg(nugg_needed%9)
        if(nugg_needed>=6):
            return int(nugg_needed/6), optimize_nugg(nugg_needed%6)
        else:
            return nugg_needed

print(optimize_nugg(139))
```

Comment: I probably wasnt clear enough in original post but the first priority is making sure there is no remainder and THEN optimizing for pack size.  so for 139 the answer would be 5 20-packs, 3 9-packs, and 2 6-packs.  In any case i am still trying to learn recursion and your solution is great to help better understand how it works.  Thanks!